# How to select range and add event in js-full-year calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, jquery-events

I would like to know how to select the range and add an event in js-year-calendar.
my code is shown below.

Now I can select days and display on the console, but I would like to register this selected event and would like to display it in calendar.

If you already have some method, please let me know.

This code is referred to documentation below:

https://year-calendar.github.io/js-year-calendar/documentation

```js
new Calendar('.calendar', {
  style: 'background',
  dataSource: [{
    startDate: new Date(2019, 1, 4),
    endDate: new Date(2019, 1, 15),
    color: "yellow"
  }, {
    startDate: new Date(2019, 3, 5),
    endDate: new Date(2019, 5, 15),
    color: "yellow"
  }],
  enableRangeSelection: true
});

document.querySelector('.calendar').addEventListener('selectRange', function(e) {
  console.log("Select the range: " + e.startDate + " - " + e.endDate);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like [this](https://codepen.io/Talk2Atheist/pen/vYYRQZx)?

```
// Create a dataSource variable  

let dataSource = [
    {
        startDate: new Date(2019, 1, 4),
        endDate: new Date(2019, 1, 15),
        color: "yellow"
    }, {
        startDate: new Date(2019, 3, 5),
        endDate: new Date(2019, 5, 15),
        color: "yellow"
    }
]

// Create the calendar with the dataSource

let calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
    style: 'background',
    dataSource: dataSource,
    enableRangeSelection: true
});


document.querySelector('#calendar').addEventListener('selectRange', function(e) {
    // Append the new data to dataSource 
    dataSource.push({
        startDate: e.startDate,
        endDate: e.endDate,
        color: "red"
    })

    // Set the updated dataSource as main source
    calendar.setDataSource(dataSource)
});
```